# Using RxJava to chain request on a single thread

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I'm saving the user's location in the app local database and then send it to the server. Once the server return a success, I delete the location that was sent.

Each time a point has been saved in the database I call this method:

```
public void sendPoint(){
    amazonRetrofit.postAmazonPoints(databaseHelper.getPoints())
            .map(listIdsSent -> deleteDatabasePoints(listIdsSent))
            .doOnCompleted(() -> emitStoreChange(finalEvent))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.from(backgroundLooper))
            .subscribe();
}
```

1. I query the database for the point to be send to the server
2. I received from the server the list of point successfully sent
3. Using `.map()`, I gather the point successfully sent and delete them from the local database

Sometimes, It happens that I call this method repeatedly without having wait for the previous request to be completed and deleted the point sent. So, when I call that method again, it will post the same point as the previous request because that previous request isn't completed yet thus haven't deleted the point using the `.map()` yet. Causing the server to receive duplicates...

**Timeline**

---

- *1st Call to `postPoint()`*
- Retrive point **A,B,C** from the database
- **Post** point **A,B,C** to the server
- *2nd call to `postPoint()`*
- Retrive point **A,B,C,D** from the database
- **Post** point **A,B,C,D** to the server
- Receive success from the 1st request
- Deleting **A,B,C** from the local database
- Receive success from the 2nd request
- Deleting **A,B,C,D** from the local database

**Result:**

The server database now have received : **A,B,C,A,B,C,D**

Each request occurs sequentially but somehow the same location points are sent to the server when I call `sendPoint()` too quickly. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First to all you are not using observerOn operator properly, observeOn operator is applied over the steps in your pipeline, once is defined. 
So if you define at the end of the pipeline just before subscribeOn, then none of your previous steps will be executed in that thread.

Also, since you need to wait until the response of your server call, you can use the callbacks handlers that Subscriber already provide (onNext(), onComplete())

```
 public void sendPoint(){
    Observable.from(databaseHelper.getPoints())
              .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
              .flatMap(poins-> amazonRetrofit.postAmazonPoints(points))
              .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.from(backgroundLooper))
              .subscribe(listIdsSent-> deleteDatabasePoints(listIdsSent), () -> emitStoreChange(finalEvent));
}
```

if you want to see more examples of ObserverOn and SubscribeOn you can take a look here. https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/scheduler/ObservableAsynchronous.java

Comment: Really helpful, that website is really clear to understand. I'm just confuse in your example, why is there two call to postPoint() in the .map()?

Comment: that was a typo. I already update the answer. If that resolve your problem remember to mark as complete

Comment: In your example, the first .from(databaseHelper.getPoint()) will be executed on the main thread since the observeOn is underneath? Thus still causing my issue that the database is queryied to soon if I call that method quickly... How could I be sure to execute the from() only when the looper thread is ready for the next request? (I don't know if i'm beibg clear here)

Comment: And i think you switched up the AndroidScheduler otherwise this would block the UI when doing the amazonRetrofit.postPoint() which returns an Observable

Comment: The only observable iny example is amazonRetrofit.postPoint(points) ... I'm confused here that you put it in the map

Comment: If amazonRetrofit.postPoint() returns an observable you can change map operator by flatMap

Comment: Will it take the parent observer thread if I don't specify one?

Comment: Observable.from(databaseHelper.getPoints()) it will be run in the main thread, but you can always specify where do you want this observable be runned when it´s created using     Observable.from(databaseHelper.getPoints(), AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

Comment: Last question here, if I put both observeOn(AndroidScheduler.MainThread()) AND subscribeOn(AndroidScheduler.newThread()) and the beginning of the chain, which one would be take in accounts for the rest of the chain?

Comment: SubscribeOn take a look of the unit test that I paste you in the github link

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot, I'm working. Try to look please the examples that I provide to you

Comment: I read those during the night...lol Just to make it clear, it would be pointless to use a observeOn AND a subscribeOn at the same time if its always the subscribeOn that will take the control of the schedule?

Comment: I just found an Article that says otherwise------>  In summary, subscribeOn() instructs the source Observable which thread to emit items on, and this thread will push items all the way to the Subscriber. However, if it encounters an observeOn() somewhere in the chain (discussed shortly), it will then pass emissions to another thread for the remaining operations at that point.

Comment: Yes, but that's logical. Take a look the github project. I commit a couple unit test with combination of observeOn and subscribeOn

Answer (score 1):

You should have some kind of validation on the client side or/and on the backend side.

Client side:
The simplest solution is to add two columns to the table with locations like "processing" and "uploaded".
When you select locations from database and clausure `where processing=false and uploaded=false`.
Then when you have rows ready to sent set `processing=true` and when the server returns success set `done=true`.

Backend side (optional, depends on requirements):
You should send location with timestamp to the server (probably one more additional column in your client side table). If the server gets a location with timestamp older than the last one in a database it shouldn't store it.

RxJava solution:
You can implement a similar solution with memory cache which is kept around all `sendPoint` as `List`.

Pseudocode:

```
public void sendPoint(){
      databaseHelper.getPoints()
            .filter(points -> pointsNotInCache())
            .map(points -> amazonRetrofit.postAmazonPoints())
            .map(points -> addToCache()) 
            .map(listIdsSent -> deleteDatabasePoints(listIdsSent))
            .map(listIdsSent -> removeSentPointsFromCache()) //if you would like save memory
            .doOnCompleted(() -> emitStoreChange(finalEvent))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.from(backgroundLooper))
            .subscribe();
}
```

Comment: I might end up using this as it's probably less of a hassle than RxJava, but I would still like to know how to do this in full RxJava, as I'm convibce it's possible

Comment: databasehelper.getPoints() isn't an Observable though

Comment: @Jaythaking you can make it simply `Observable` by `Observable.from(list)`

Comment: Okay and amazonRetrofit.postPoints(points) in your example lack his argument and it's supposed to return an Observable... I'm a little lost here

Comment: try with `flatMap(points->amazonRetrofit.postPoints(points))` BTW. As I mentioned it's a pseudocode. I gave you an idea. Don't expect from SO always copy-paste ready solutions ;)

Comment: Of course :p... But still both solution you gave me are using a cache system, I'm sure there is a way without needing caching... I mean, it execute on a single thread, so I should be able to avoid that race condition issue

Comment: Problem seems to be that the database is queryed RIGHT on every method call instead of at the beginning of each server request

Comment: Thanks for your help btw

Comment: What would it do exactly? And why don't you recommend it? :P

Comment: I read that there might be a way using SynchronizedSubject class of RxJava, but I didn't find any example that suits my needs

Comment: If it was helpful in *any way* at least upvote the answer, please. Saying "thanks" for spending the time to solve other people problems might be not enough :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, as everyone else is saying, you need an intermediate cache.

i.e.

```
HashSet<Point> mHashSet = new HashSet<>();

public void sendPoint() {
    Observable.from(databaseHelper.getPoints())
        .filter(point -> !mHashSet.contains(point))
        .doOnNext(mHashSet::put)
        .toList()
        .flatMap(amazonRetrofit::postAmazonPoints)
        .map(this::deleteDatabasePoints)
        .doOnCompleted(() -> emitStoreChange(finalEvent))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.from(backgroundLooper))
        .subscribe();
}
```